# Reading/Writing to file array of structure in C

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to write into txt file array of structure and then load it back. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TEXT_LEN 100
struct Data_s
{
    char name[TEXT_LEN];
    char brand[TEXT_LEN];
    char invNr[TEXT_LEN];
    long year;
};

long saveDB(struct Data_s* items, long len, char* outputFile);
long loadDB(struct Data_s* items, long len, char* inputFile);

int main()
{
    struct Data_s std[2];
    struct Data_s* ptr;
    int i;
    ptr = std;
    strcpy(ptr->name, "cat");
    strcpy(ptr->brand, "catTest");
    strcpy(ptr->invNr, "123456");
    ptr->year = 2000;
    ptr++;
    strcpy(ptr->name, "lion");
    strcpy(ptr->brand, "lionTest");
    strcpy(ptr->invNr, "100000");
    ptr->year = 2020;
    ptr = std;
    saveDB(ptr, 2, "try.txt");
    loadDB(ptr, 2, "try.txt");
}

long saveDB(struct Data_s* items, long len, char* outputFile)
{
    FILE* fpOut;
    if ((fpOut = fopen(outputFile, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file - quitting\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int i;
    // fprintf(fpOut,"name brand invNr year \n");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fpOut, "%s %s %s %li \n", items->name, items->brand, items->invNr, items->year);

        items++;
    }
    fclose(fpOut);

    return 0;
}

long loadDB(struct Data_s* items, long len, char* inputFile)
{
    char* num[100];
    FILE* fptr;

    if ((fptr = fopen(inputFile, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");

        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fptr, "%s", *num);

    printf("Value of n=%s", *num);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It is writing file properly and I am getting semgentation fault when program starts to read from file.

Anyone has idea to help me to write this properly and to read back from file to structure?

Thank you

Comment: thank you, any idea how to read back from txt file to structure?

Comment: Consider using a textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/) or a stable binary format like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) databases. You will find libraries for both. These libraries are opensource, so you can study their source code, at least for inspiration.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I'd suggest you to explicitly define all those ```long``` variables to ```long int```.

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website. Next time, provide some [mre] in your question. If you have [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` -all warnings and debug info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `ptr++`, your `ptr` is pointing to the second element. And in your `saveDB` function, you are trying to write one *past* the last element.

You should pass the address of the first element of `std` to your `saveDB` and `loadDB` functions.

One way to read would be:

```
long loadDB(struct Data_s *items,long len,char *inputFile)
{
        int i = 0;
        FILE *fptr;

        if ((fptr = fopen(inputFile,"r")) == NULL){
                printf("Error! opening file");

                // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
                return 1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %s %li", items->name, items->brand, items->invNr, &items->year);
                items++;
        }

        fclose(fptr);

        return 0;
}
```

And in your `main` function, you could print the values like so:

```
printf("Name=%s\n", ptr->name);
printf("Brand=%s\n", ptr->brand);
printf("invNr=%s\n", ptr->invNr);
printf("year=%ld\n", ptr->year);

ptr++;

printf("Name=%s\n", ptr->name);
printf("Brand=%s\n", ptr->brand);
printf("invNr=%s\n", ptr->invNr);
printf("year=%ld\n", ptr->year);
```

Comment: I added ptr=std, now writing is good but I am not clear how to correct saveDB function

Comment: could you please show on code, how to read from txt file and save in structure. Thank you so much

Comment: I reall appreciate your help.  Thank you so much